# What happens when I try to write a file ( say text) that consumes more memory than the RAM?

Tags: memory-management, operating-system

Suppose I open notepad ( not necessarily ) and write a text file of 6 GB ( again, suppose) . I have no running processes other than notepad itself, and the memory assigned to the user processes has a limit of less than 6 GB. My disc memory is sufficient though.
What happens to the file now? I know that writing is definitely possible and virtual memory may get involved , but I am not sure how. Does virtual memory actually get involved? Either way, can you please explain what happens from an OS point of view?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From the memory point of view, the notepad allocates a 6Gb buffer in memory to store the text you're seeing. The process consists of data segment (which includes the buffer above, but not only) and a code segment (the notepad native code), so the total process space is going to be larger than 6Gb.

Now, it's all virtual memory as far the process is concerned (yes, it is involved). If I understand your case right, the process won't fit into physical memory, so it's going to crash due to insufficient memory.

Comment: So, in a way, writing a file whose size is more than the RAM isn't possible, but reading a file ( say by memory mapped file ) is possible?

Comment: Reading from the disk, you mean? Yes, it is possible, like watching a movie. The data is streamed, so effectively at any given moment only a small buffer is stored in memory, the rest is on the disk. The same way writing to a file is also possible.

Answer (score 0):

> the memory assigned to the user processes has a limit of less than 6 GB.

If this is a hard limit enforced by the operating system, it may at it's own discretion kill the process with some error message. It may also do anything else it wants, depending on it's implementation. This part of the answer disregards virtual memory or any other way of swapping RAM to disk.

> My disc memory is sufficient though. What happens to the file now? I know that writing is definitely possible and virtual memory may get involved , but I am not sure how.

At this point, when your question starts involving the disk, we can start talking about virtual memory and swapping. If virtual memory is involved and the 6GB limit is in RAM usage, not total virtual memory usage, parts of the file can be moved to disk. This could be parts of the file currently out of view on screen or similar. The OS then manages what parts of the (more than 6GB of) data is available in RAM, and swaps in/out data depending on what the program needs (i.e. where in the file you are working).

> Does virtual memory actually get involved?

Depends on weather it is enabled in the OS in question or not, and how it is configured.

---

Yes a lot of this depends on the OS in question and it's implementation and how it handles cases like this. If the OS is poorly written it may crash itself.

Answer (score 0):

Before I give you a precise answer, let me explain few things.

I could suggest you to open Linux System Monitor or Windows Task Manager, and then open heavy softwares like a game, Android Studio, IntelliJ e.t.c

Go to the memory visualization tap. You will notice that each of the applications( processes) consume a certain amount of memory. Okey fine!

Some machines if not most, support memory virtualization.
It's a concept of allocating a certain amount of the hard disk space as a back up plan just in case some application( process) consumes a lot of memory and if it is not active at times, then it gets moved from the main memory to the virtual memory to create a priority for other tasks that are currently busy.

A virtual memory is slower that the main memory as it is located in the hard disk. However is it still faster than fetching data directly from the disk.

When launching any application, not all its application size will be loaded to memory, but only the necessary files that are required at that particular time will be loaded to memory. Thus why you can play a 60GB game in a machine that has a 4GB RAM.

To answer your question:
If you happen to launch a software that consumes all the memory resources of your machine, your machine will freeze. You will even hear the sounds made by its cooling system. It will be louder and faster.

I hope I clarified this well